# What does upappeased mean?

Tags: meaning

The word upappeased appears in a poem by  [Renee Vivien](https://allpoetry.com/poem/8593949-The-Touch-by-Renee-Vivien). It doesn't appear to be in the OED and I am not sure what it means.

"I
follow slowly the graceful contours of your hips,
The curves of your shoulders, your neck, your upappeased breasts."

Comment: I can't find *upappease* in any dictionary. It's likely to be a misprint (or mistranslation, or misapprehension) for *unappeased,* which would certainly fit the context. But since it's poetry — of a sort — it's unlikely we'll ever know without referring to an actual primary source. Someone here may have that access.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I think you are right. The original French seems to be Je suis avec lenteur le contour de tes hanches,
Tes épaules, ton col, tes seins inapaisés.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about a misprint - of a *translation* involving an extremely unusual poetic / figurative usage for which any "meaning" would be a matter of opinion anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I too wondered about the misprint aspect. But from other comments, it seems to be a misprint that has proliferated. If we care about accurate usage we should leave such questions open so that inaccurate usage is discouraged among our readers. Closure would merely hide away the correction of error and help no-one. As for the meaning, it is as unambiguously clear as can reasonably be desired for an adjective in the given context. So I did not vote for closure.

Comment: @Anton: *Proliferated?* How many translations of an obscure French poem can there be? And even if we know what the "correct" English word should be, and/or we know the French word ***inapaisés***, it's still entirely a matter of opinion exactly what that highly figurative / poetic usage might actually *mean*. Frankly, I think the question has no meaningful connection to the process of learning English as a second language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original is:

> [Canalblog](http://www.barapoemes.net/archives/2020/12/09/38698161.html)
> Je suis avec lenteur le contour de tes hanches,
> Tes épaules, ton col, tes seins inapaisés.
> Mon désir délicat se refuse aux baisers ;
> Il effleure et se pâme en des voluptés blanches.

The root word is **inapaisés**, which translates as “unsatisfied”, or similar notions embraced by **unappeased**. The sensual meaning is then clear.

Your text is therefore a misprint.

Comment: It's not just the one text. About 2/3 of Google results have this typo.